# 'Manage display': new fields not draggable

Tags: entities, javascript

When I try to drag'n'drop a field under '*Manage display*' / inside a *view mode* (e.g. "Teaser") it just doesn't stay above the *Hidden* fold. First the confirmation message is shown. But as soon as that fades out, the field 'jumps' back to the *Hidden* section. And instead of the field I just dropped above the *Hidden* fold, the field list only shows "No field is displayed".

[image]

It did of course work before. Since then I have installed the module "update jquery" – but I suppose that's not the problem since all other drag'n'drop UIs seem to work perfectly fine.

Also I had the module "Entity view modes" installed – but I disabled it because I first thought that that might have caused the problem. Now it's off – but the bug is still there.

Caches are of course flushed, and no errors in firebug's console.

Anybody any ideas what could be wrong? Any pointers? Thank you!

**Update:** When setting the *format* manually from '*Hidden*' to '*Default*' (or any other state) everything seems to be ok: the field jumps right up above the *Hidden* fold. Also fields that once were 'active' I can still drag'n'drop into active and inactive state. Only *new fields* seem to be not draggabe. Strange – but for now I think I can live with that. But still: if anybody has any suggerstion I would gladly appreciate it.